# ! LaTeX Error: Bad math environment delimiter

Tags: equations, enumerate

I can't figure out the error I made in this sample, can anyone help me?
The code is:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item blalblabla
\item blablabla
\item blablalba
\item This difference is due to correlations becoming arbitrary when the 
points are clustered together closely, which happens when the real and
fake dataset are quite alike and the $F_{1}$ scores only differ 
$\pm1%$. The results is the fourth value for the similarity score:  
$S_{est}$. Formally, this is
\begin{equation}\label{eq:Sregr}
S_{est}^{regr}=\rho_{pearson}(RMSE(E_{R}),RMSE(E_{F}))
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}\label{eq:Sclass}
S^{class}_{est}=1-MAPE(F_{1}(E_{R}),F_{1}(E_{F})
\end{equation}
where $RMSE$ and $F_{1}$ return the scores of the given estimators on both test sets.
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

The error messages are:

```
! LaTeX Error: Bad math environment delimiter.
l.306 \begin{equation}
\label{eq:Sregr}
Your command was ignored.
Type I <command> <return> to replace it with another command,
or <return> to continue without it.
! You can't use `\eqno' in math mode.
\endmathdisplay@a ...\df@tag \@empty \else \veqno
\alt@tag \df@tag \fi \ifx ...
l.308 \end{equation}
Sorry, but I'm not programmed to handle this case;
I'll just pretend that you didn't ask for it.
If you're in the wrong mode, you might be able to
return to the right one by typing `I}' or `I$' or `I\par'.
! Missing \endgroup inserted.
<inserted text>
\endgroup
l.308 \end{equation}
I've inserted something that you may have forgotten.
(See the <inserted text> above.)
With luck, this will get me unwedged. But if you
really didn't forget anything, try typing `2' now; then
my insertion and my current dilemma will both disappear.
! LaTeX Error: \begin{enumerate} on input line 298 ended by \end{equation}.
l.308 \end{equation}
Your command was ignored.
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text>
$
l.308 \end{equation}
I've inserted something that you may have forgotten.
(See the <inserted text> above.)
With luck, this will get me unwedged. But if you
really didn't forget anything, try typing `2' now; then
my insertion and my current dilemma will both disappear.
! LaTeX Error: \begin{document} ended by \end{enumerate}.
l.315 \end{enumerate}
Your command was ignored.
Type I <command> <return> to replace it with another command,
or <return> to continue without it.
! Extra \endgroup.
<recently read> \endgroup
l.315 \end{enumerate}
Things are pretty mixed up, but I think the worst is over.
```

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a Minimal Working Example, instead of a code snippet.

Comment: works fine with the `article` document class and `enumerate` package loaded

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Also we can't say, what is wrong with document, where you use your code fragment. You need to extend your code fragment to complete small document, which reproduce your problem. Your code fragment doesn't contain any error (however, it will be more appropriate to use `align` or `gather` math environment determined in the `amsmath` package).

Comment: Try this strategy to localize the problem: 1) make a backup copy of your document. 2) delete the whole enumerate-environment and compile (should be fine). 3) add only \begin and \end statements of enumerate from your backup; compile. 4) add more lines (not all at once) and compile. // At some point errors should show up. Have a closer look at your last changes.

Comment: Most likely not the real issue (but who knows, without a full MWE), but you shouldn't put a `\par` (blank line) before `\begin{equation}`.

Comment: plesase show the error message from the document that you posted. Currently the error shown is from a different document, which makes it impossible to debug,

Comment: You have a `%$` so that `$` is sommented out. If you want a % use `\%`.

Answer (score 2):

Too long that can be a comment ...

Your document, which contain shoved code fragment, is very wrong structured. Your code fragment is, as I already mentioned in the comment, without any error (however, it could has been better written). A simple, correct MWE (Minimal Working Example), a small but complete document for testing your code fragment, can be:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item blalblabla
\item blablabla
\item blablalba
\item blablalba Formally, this is
%
\begin{equation}\label{eq:Sregr}
S_{est}^{regr}=\rho_{pearson}(RMSE(E_{R}),RMSE(E_{F}))
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}\label{eq:Sclass}
S^{class}_{est}=1-MAPE(F_{1}(E_{R}),F_{1}(E_{F})
\end{equation}

where $RMSE$ and $F_{1}$ return the scores of the given estimators on both test sets.
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

which works fine (no warnings, no errors). However, I would write your code fragment on the following way:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item blalblabla
\item blablabla
\item blablalba
\item blablalba Formally, this is
%
\begin{align}
S_{\mathrm{est}}^{\mathrm{regr}}
    & = \rho_{\mathrm{pearson}}(\mathrm{RMSE}(E_{R}),\mathrm{RMSE}(E_{F}))  \label{eq:Sregr}    \\
S^{\mathrm{class}}_{\mathrm{est}}
    & = 1 - \mathrm{MAPE}(F_{1}(E_{R}),F_{1}(E_{F})        \label{eq:Sclass}
\end{align}

where RMSE and $F_{1}$ return the scores of the given estimators on both test sets.
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

which gives more correct (variables as clear distinguished from text indices) indices and nicer result (equations are aligned and keep together):

[image]

To find source of your problem, please compare structure of the first MWE with structure of your document. Are code fragment is inside document body (after `\begin{document)`)?

For more help, you need to provide complete small document (as are above examples), which reproduce your problem. Unfortunately our crystal ball are fogy, so we cannot see your document in it :-( ).

Comment: @José Carlos Santos, thank you for editing of answer!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for not posing a MWE, I'll do better in future posts. It was my mistake you couldn't reproduce the error and solve the issue as I did not post the complete code.

Thank you for your help, the problem was of another nature but could not be seen by you as the error was in the text after the fourth \item (I edited my question with the concerning part). There I wrote `$\pm1%$` instead of `$\pm 1\%$` which caused the errors.